# How to say "piggish dinner"?

Tags: colloquial-language, slang

What would be the closest Japanese equivalent to English adjective *piggish* with the sense number [2](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/piggish), like in "We had a piggish dinner"?

I came up with two literal translations:

1. 豚のような夕食を食べた。
2. 豚っぽい夕食を食べた。

and one figurative:

飽くなき夕食を食べた。

None of them seem to be natural.

Definition of [piggish](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/piggish)

adjective

1. resembling a pig, especially in being slovenly, greedy, or gluttonous: piggish table manners
2. (of food portions) indecently large
3. stubborn

Comment: I think it's better to rephrase *piggish dinner* to clarify what it means.

Comment: Good point, I will add the definition. Though it should have been clear from the given context.

Comment: Hmm, this isn't a phrase that this native speaker of English is familiar with. What variety of English is it idiomatic in? Googling the phrase returns very few hits, suggesting that this isn't idiomatic in any variety.

Comment: I feel like people I know might say "we ate like pigs," but yeah, I've never personally heard or used "piggish dinner."

Comment: I just searched "piggish meal" and got a few hits. Dinner is a type of meal. Do you want me to change the question to meal? My question is about the attributive, and not the attributed word. Merriam-Webster has definitions for  piggish, piggishness and pigging-out.

Comment: I would advise that you first check what kinds of Google hits "piggish meal" is actually bringing up. I'm not convinced this is a real idiomatic use of the adjective.

Comment: #2 seems missing in wikitionary https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/piggish

Comment: Wiktionary is not an authoritative source, Merriam-Webster is.

Comment: Merriam-Webster only lists *1: of, relating to, or suggestive of a pig and 2: having qualities associated with a pig*

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/piggish

Comment: In my local dialect as well, "piggish" could only describe the eater, not the meal.

Answer (score 2):

So my ChatGPT says "'Piggish meal' refers to a meal that is excessively large or indulgent". If this is what you're trying to express, none of your suggestions will work as expected.

豚のような食事 or 豚の餌のような食事 is grammatically correct, but it's not an idiomatic expression and what it actually refers to would depend on the context. I think people usually imagine a meal that is like livestock feed and makes humans sick if they eat it.

飽くなき usually modifies 冒険心, 好奇心 and so on. 飽くなき夕食 simply sounds funny
and puzzling to me.

The safest way to describe this would simply be 過度に量が多い食事 or something. If you want a catchy and humorous phrase suitable for the title of an online video, I usually see expressions like メガ盛りの◯◯, バカ盛りの◯◯, デブ専用◯◯ and so on.